# From C to Shell: About "system" instruction

Tags: c, shell

I´m trying to convert some C/C++ code to UNIX shell. I´ve some conversions but, sometimes, I find the code in C/C++ odd, maybe because I do not understand it in the context. Even more, the client did not give me the input/output files or documentation, so it is terrible difficult for coding in UNIX.

I got this:

```
int exec_ftpcmd(char *ftpcmd, char *IP_Server, char* icmd)
{
    int cmd_st = 0;
    FILE  *cmd_file;
    char  *cmd_fname = "ftp_exe.cmd",
          *out_fname = "ftp_exe.out",
           cmd[100];

    printf("ftp_serv: exec_ftpcmd [%s][%s] \n",icmd,ftpcmd);

    cmd_file = fopen(cmd_fname,"w");
#ifndef UNIX
    fprintf(cmd_file,"user test test1\n");  //just for dos
#endif
    if (strlen(icmd)>0)
        fprintf(cmd_file,"cd %s\n",icmd);
    fprintf(cmd_file,"%s\n",ftpcmd);
    fprintf(cmd_file,"quit ");
    fclose(cmd_file);
    memset(cmd,0,sizeof(cmd));

#ifdef UNIX
    sprintf(cmd,"more %s | ftp -v %s >> %s",cmd_fname,IP_Server,out_fname);  //unix
#else
    sprintf(cmd,"ftp -n -s:%s %s >> %s",cmd_fname,IP_Server,out_fname);  //dos
#endif
    cmd_st = system(cmd);

    return cmd_st;

}
```

I think that I read from a file that has a lot of commands, and test it with "system", to see if they are OK? Could I do the same in UNIX with **exec**?

I read [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/system.html) that **system** has some perils. It is safe to use it in this context?

So, which one is good equivalence of **system**? Should I use it? Is there a more elegant way?

**EDIT**
I found a mini example of the **ftp_exe.cmd**:

```
 ever@/narcredit/vcfid>cat ftp_exe.cmd
 dir /apps/VB/A01862.txt ftp_dir.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

The commands in the first argument are executed by ftp and the results appended to an output file. The use of `more` is strange in this context. A single line of shell should be enough:

```
ftp -v $IP_SERVER >> ftp_exe.out
```

with the inputs in the first argument and an appropriate cd/user command given over stdin. In a whole line, this might look like:

```
( echo "cd $icmd"; echo $ftpcmd; echo "quit") | ftp -v $ipaddress >> ftp_exe.out
```

Comment: In the example, the `cd` is to be executed by the ftp client.  A solution that fits the example better would be:  `(echo "cd $icmd"; echo $ftpcmd; echo "quit") | ftp -v $ipaddress >> $out_fname`